# Change name result query

Tags: mysql

I tried this query

```
select count(id) as id_name, category as media  
from tb_gadar
where d BETWEEN '2018-04-01' and '2019-12-31'
and category in ('Laki-laki','Perempuan')`
```

and the result is `144, Laki-laki`

How do I change `Laki-laki` to `Umum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `CASE` statement to do that

```
select count(id) as id_name, 
       case when category = 'Laki-laki'  then 'Umum' else category end as media  
from tb_gadar
where d BETWEEN '2018-04-01' and '2019-12-31'
and category in ('Laki-laki','Perempuan')
group by category
```